# routing by frontName like {frontName}/[params1]/[paramsX]...[?queryString] in magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Magento2 processing requests with the structure like:

`{frontName}/{controller}/{action}`

but i need to process some requests with the structure like

`{frontName}/[params1]/[paramsX]...[?queryString]`

what's the best way to solve it? 
Event linstener for controller_front_send_response_before? 
Interceptor for Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Route? 
or any other ... thanks very much

maybe .htaccess rewrite?

Comment: You need to use a custom router - [here](https://github.com/zoransalamun/magento2-custom-router/blob/master/Controller/Router.php) is an example

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks very much! i'll try it immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank for @RobbieAverill's comment. the [link](https://github.com/zoransalamun/magento2-custom-router/blob/master/Controller/Router.php) is useful.

i created `di.xml` in `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/frontend` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="app_api_router" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

</config>
```

and created `Router.php`  in `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Controller/Router.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\AppApi\Controller;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if(strpos($identifier, 'routes.xml frontName') === 0) {
            // MY LOGIC CODE HERE
        }
    }
}
```